# What is the equivalent of private static readonly field in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am aiming to create a private static readonly *field* in VB.NET.

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private Static ReadOnly someField As Regex = New Regex("somePattern")
End Class
```

This attempts to create a static property with only get access, but fails with the error:

> 'Static' is not valid on a member variable declaration.

In C#, I'd create this as follows:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly Regex someField = new Regex("somePattern");
}
```

How can I create and initialize a field in this similar manner in VB.NET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Private Shared ReadOnly
```

The VB equivalent to `static` members is `Shared` members.